# Android Lockscreen Ring Code available?

Tags: android, view, frameworks, lockscreen

To give an application a more android-like feeling I'd like to switch the style of choosing between two "ways" to something like the lockscreen-ring, where you can drag the center to the right/left. I've googled a lot, only thing I've "found" was that the Android code must be somewhere hidden in the framework APK file, so I thought maybe you guys know where I could find something like that, or an 3rd party "view" under free license?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the open source [GlowPadView](https://github.com/nadavfima/GlowPadView/) for Android 3.0 and above. There is no implementation available for Gingerbread and below AFAIK, and you will have to make one yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I've read that it's extracted from the framework or something? - I'll keep looking for a GB version.. otherwise I'll have to fix this one. :)

Comment: @damian Yeah. The developer of the project took it from the ICS or JB code and modified it to compile on its own as a general tool.